# Looking for a mind map macOS app, which allows for multiple parent nodes

Tags: macos, mind-mapping

I'm using MindNode so far, and it's great, but I need something that allows me to assign more than one parent node to a child node. Is there anything you can recommend?

Comment: I am not familiar with MindNode, but in software such as Xmind you can very easily "fake" this, by creating and attaching custom relationship connections. See here: https://xmind.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/14386651-is-it-possible-to-create-a-node-with-two-parents-not-concept-map-